# Find an integer $x \in \{0, . . . , 196\} $ which solves the equation $x^{131} \equiv 12 \mod 197$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I complete this? Obviously, I can guess and check however my calculator doesn't display these large numbers... Is there some sort of method to calculate this?

Comment: The answer is 152, you can check it.

Comment: @Olimjon How did you get 152? What steps did you take?

Comment: Programmistic calculations, but I do not know yet about the method to calculate without programming, if I had I posted as an answer...

Comment: This may be of use to you: You are trying to find the kernel of the polynomial function $p(x)=x^{131}-12$ where $p: \mathbb Z_{197} \to \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 4):

Since $197$ is a prime, Fermat's little theorem tells you that $x^{196}\equiv 1\pmod{197}$ for all $x$ coprime to $197$. Square that and you get $x^{392}\equiv 1\pmod{197}$ and thus $x^{393}\equiv x\pmod{197}$ for all $x$ coprime to $197$.

Now let $x$ have the desired propery and cube it; then you get
$$x\equiv x^{393}\equiv 12^3\equiv 1728\equiv 152\pmod{197}$$
This shows that $152$ is the solution for the equation.

Comment: how'd u get from x^393 to 12^3?

Comment: @SamEd: $x^{393}=x^{131\cdot 3}=(x^{131})^3\equiv 12^3$ since $x^{131}\equiv 12$